# What's the best way to deal with an error about an unmounted component? Trying to implement CKEditor but get this error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ckeditor, react-state

I get the following error once I implement my CKeditor to a react Modal:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

The CKeditor appears on line 132, here is the code of the implementation:

```
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import { MoreHorizOutlined, ShareOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
import ArrowUpwardOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpwardOutlined";
import ArrowDownwardOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownwardOutlined";
import RepeatOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RepeatOutlined";
import ChatBubbleOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleOutlineOutlined";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../style/Post.css";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectQuestionId,
  selectQuestionName,
  setQuestionInfo,
} from "../features/questionSlice";
import db from "../firebase";
import { selectUser } from "../features/userSlice";
import firebase from "firebase";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

function Post({ Id, question, imageUrl, timestamp, buildFaastUser }) {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const questionId = useSelector(selectQuestionId);
  const questionName = useSelector(selectQuestionName);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
  const [getAnswer, setGetAnswer] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (questionId) {
      db.collection("questions")
        .doc(questionId)
        .collection("answer")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
          setGetAnswer(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, answers: doc.data() }))
          )
        );
    }
  }, [questionId]);

  const handleAnswer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (questionId) {
      db.collection("questions").doc(questionId).collection("answer").add({
        questionId: questionId,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        answer: answer,
        user: user,
      });

      console.log(questionId, questionName);
      setAnswer("");
      setOpenModal(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="post"
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(
          setQuestionInfo({
            questionId: Id,
            questionName: question,
          })
        )
      }
    >
      <div className="post__info">
        <Avatar src={buildFaastUser.photo} />
        <h5>
          {buildFaastUser.displayName
            ? buildFaastUser.displayName
            : buildFaastUser.email}
        </h5>
        <small>{new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}</small>
      </div>
      <div className="post__body">
        <div className="post__question">
          <p>{question}</p>
          <button
            onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}
            className="post__btnAnswer"
          >
            Answer
          </button>

          <Modal
            isOpen={openModal}
            onRequestClose={() => setOpenModal(false)}
            shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
            style={{
              overlay: {
                width: 680,
                height: 550,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                boxShadow:
                  "box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);",
                zIndex: "1000",
                top: "50%",
                left: "50%",
                marginTop: "-250px",
                marginLeft: "-350px",
              },
            }}
          >
            <div className="modal__question">
              <h1>{question}</h1>
              <p>
                asked by{" "}
                <span className="name">
                  {buildFaastUser.displayName
                    ? buildFaastUser.displayName
                    : buildFaastUser.email}
                </span>{" "}
                {""}
                on{" "}
                <span className="name">
                  {new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal__answer">
              <CKEditor
                required
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                data={answer}
                onChange={(e, editor) => {
                  const data = editor.getData();
                  setAnswer(e.target.data);
                }}
                placeholder="Enter your answer"
                type="text"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="modal__button">
              <button className="cancel" onClick={() => setOpenModal(false)}>
                Cancel
              </button>
              <button onClick={handleAnswer} type="submit" className="add">
                Add Answer
              </button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
        <div className="post__answer">
          {getAnswer.map(({ id, answers }) => (
            <p key={id} style={{ position: "relative", paddingBottom: "5px" }}>
              {Id === answers.questionId ? (
                <span>
                  {answers.answer}
                  <br />
                  <span
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      color: "gray",
                      fontSize: "small",
                      display: "flex",
                      right: "0px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <span style={{ color: "lightblue" }}>
                      {answers.user.displayName
                        ? answers.user.displayName
                        : answers.user.email}{" "}
                      on{" "}
                      {new Date(answers.timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
        <img src={imageUrl} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="post__footer">
        <div className="post__footerAction">
          <ArrowUpwardOutlinedIcon />
          <ArrowDownwardOutlinedIcon />
        </div>

        <RepeatOutlinedIcon />
        <ChatBubbleOutlineOutlinedIcon />
        <div className="post__footerLeft">
          <ShareOutlined />
          <MoreHorizOutlined />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

I'm new to react so there may be some basics I'm missing out in terms of implementation. I definitely know the issue is with the CKeditor implementation but I'm not sure what the issue is because it's a fairly simple component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the unmounted error by setting a local variable mounted to true, I've set it to false on the cleanup function of the effect (like suggested by react). Then I'm updating the state if and only if that value is true, that is if the component is un-mounted meaning our variable is set to false, it wont enter the if block.

Here is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (questionId) {
      db.collection("questions")
        .doc(questionId)
        .collection("answer")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          if (mounted) {
            setGetAnswer(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, answers: doc.data() }))
            );
          }
        });
    }

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, [questionId]);
```